# How to change Sublime Text Packages directory location?

Tags: sublimetext2

I would like to change the Packages directory location or add a new one (to be on network drive.)

I can't use the symlink.

I had a look on the plugins, but can't find.

I am on Windows Vista, Windows 8 (soon.)

Thank you for your help.

Christophe

Comment: Just a comment: In Sublime Python interpreter issuing `sublime.packages_path()` prints the path of packages folder. Thou I'm not too familiar with ST, nor have an idea how this variable is initialized.

Comment: Yes. But we can't set a value with this method. Thank you.

Comment: Probably not possible

Comment: You are probably right. It seems to be that we can use symlinks with network drives on Windows 7 & 8. Then I will have to wait for it. Thank you for your comments.

Answer (score 0):

If a moderator could please turn this post into a comment, because it is only a potential workaround to the issue (rather than a complete solution).

Using an OSX operating system, I am automatically backing-up (to Dropbox with a symlink) the entire SublimeText2 folder and subfolders within the application support directory.  Inasmuch as Dropbox works on different platforms, perhaps this will give the original poster some ideas to have multiple computers using the same `Packages` data.  I am successfully using this method to automatically synchronize all three (3) of my computers -- i.e., if anything changes on one computer in the `Packages` directory or subdirectories, then all computers are automatically synchronized.

Of course, back up your data on each computer before trying out this method.